# SQL based on IF case (read details)

Tags: mysql, sql

again I met some problem with the SQL and couldn't brain it. Based on below situation, we noted that **user_id repeated twice** and I wanted to **distinct/group** it up to **1 row** but there is a case that I would consider anonymous column and the logic would be to return the **row of anonymous that equal to 1** which I believe distinct could have just take them randomly? 
Anyone can enlighten me? Appreciate for response. Thank you.

```
__________________________
|user_id|anonymous|amount|
--------------------------
|   1234|        1|   100|
|    222|        0|    90|
|   1234|        0|    88|
==========================

**Final answer** should look like this.
__________________________
|user_id|anonymous|amount|
--------------------------
|   1234|        1|   100|
|    222|        0|    90|
==========================
```

Comment: Took off sql-server. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t.* from your_table t
join 
(
  select user_id, max(anonymous) as m_anon
  from your_table
  group by user_id
) x on x.user_id = t.user_id and x.m_anon = t.anonymous
```